# Unable to detect Androidx Preference library in layout file

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

I am using the androidx libraries for my new project but I cant get the android studio to detect preference library in the layout file

I have already include the dependencies in my gradle file
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="notifications"
        app:title="Enable message notifications"/>

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:title="Send feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out after some testing 
I was creating my file in layout folder instead of xml folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U3Ti.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="notifications"
        app:title="Enable message notifications"/>

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:title="Send feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

My fragment.kt file looks like

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings, rootKey)
    }

}
```